# Why is lock much slower than Monitor.TryEnter?

Tags: c#

Results

Lock: 85.3 microseconds

Monitor.TryEnter: 11.0 microseconds

Isn't the lock expanded into the same code?

Edit: Results with 1000 iterations:
Lock: 103.3 microseconds
Monitor.TryEnter: 20.2 microseconds

Code below. Thanks

```
    [Test]
    public void Lock_Performance_Test()
    {
        const int lockIterations = 100;

        Stopwatch csLock = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < lockIterations; )
        {
            lock (object1)
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        csLock.Stop();

        Stopwatch csMonitor = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < lockIterations; )
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(object1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
            {
                try
                {
                    i++;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(object1);
                }
            }
        }
        csMonitor.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Lock: {0:f1} microseconds", csLock.Elapsed.Ticks / 10M);
        Console.WriteLine("Monitor.TryEnter: {0:f1} microseconds", csMonitor.Elapsed.Ticks / 10M);;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not disputing your findings, but would suggest you try a lot more than 100 iterations.

Comment: Can you repeat the same test but using Date.Now instead (and using a suitably large number of iterations to push the numbers into the seconds).  My concern is this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q274323

Comment: For info, note that `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` isn't helping getting a simple benchmark.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't actually know the answer, but feel it's important to point out that `lock` and `Monitor.TryEnter` are **not** functionally equivalent. From [the MSDN documentation on `Monitor.TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx):

> If successful, this method acquires an
>   exclusive lock on the obj parameter.
>   This method returns immediately,
>   whether or not the lock is available.

The `lock` statement is analogous to `Monitor.Enter`, which *does* potentially block. Granted, in your example code, there shouldn't be any blocking issues; but I would wager that since `lock` provides blocking, it does a little more work (potentially) than `TryEnter` does.

---

For what it's worth, I just tried your code on my machine and got **completely** different results:

100 iterations:
`lock`: 4.4 microseconds
`Monitor.TryEnter`: 16.1 microseconds
`Monitor.Enter`: 3.9 microseconds

100000 iterations:
`lock`: 2872.5 microseconds
`Monitor.TryEnter`: 5226.6 microseconds
`Monitor.Enter`: 2432.9 microseconds

This seriously undermines my initial guess and shows that, on my system, `lock` (which performs about the same as `Monitor.Enter`) actually drastically *outperforms* `Monitor.TryEnter`.

---

Indeed, I attempted this in VS 2010 targeting both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 and, though the results were different, in each case `lock` did in fact outperform `Monitor.TryEnter`:

### Runtime version: 2.0.50727.3603

Ran 100 times, 100000 iterations each time:
**Lock: 279736.4** microseconds
**Monitor.TryEnter: 1366751.5** microseconds
Monitor.TryEnter (no timeout): 475107.3 microseconds
Monitor.Enter: 332334.1 microseconds

### Runtime version: 4.0.30128.1

Ran 100 times, 100000 iterations each time:
**Lock: 334273.7** microseconds
**Monitor.TryEnter: 1671363.4** microseconds
Monitor.TryEnter (no timeout): 531451.8 microseconds
Monitor.Enter: 316693.1 microseconds

(Notice I also tested `Monitor.TryEnter` with no timeout, as I agreed with Marc that calling `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` was almost certainly slowing down your times for `Monitor.TryEnter`--and these tests support that--though it's strange, since in *your* case apparently `lock` is *still* significantly slower.)

Based on these results I am strongly inclined to believe that your measured execution times are somehow affected by running this code with the `Test` attribute. Either that or this code is far more machine-dependent than I would have expected.

Comment: it was my initial assumption. but it is wrong. TryEnter is even slower than lock or Enter

Comment: @Andrey: That was my finding as well, it turns out. Strange that our results would be so different from the OP's.

Answer (score 5):

100 is far too few, and running in a test framework may skew things. It is also possibly (see comments) related to any additional cost associated with the *first* lock against an object; try:

- locking once outside the loop first
- doing lots more iterations
- in a console exe, at the command line, in release mode

Also, note that in 4.0 `lock` is **not** `Monitor.Enter(object)` - so expect different results in 4.0.

But I get:

```
lock: 3548ms
Monitor.TryEnter: 7008ms
Monitor.TryEnter (2): 2947ms
Monitor.Enter: 2906ms
```

From the test rig:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
static class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        const int lockIterations = 50000000;
        object object1 = new object();
        lock (object1) { Console.WriteLine("First one has to pay an extra toll"); }
        Stopwatch csLock = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < lockIterations; ) {
            lock (object1) { i++; }
        }
        csLock.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("lock: " + csLock.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        Stopwatch csMonitorTryEnter = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < lockIterations; ) {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(object1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))) {
                try { i++; } finally { Monitor.Exit(object1); }
            }
        }
        csMonitorTryEnter.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Monitor.TryEnter: " + csMonitorTryEnter.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        csMonitorTryEnter = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < lockIterations; ) {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(object1, 10000)) {
                try { i++; } finally { Monitor.Exit(object1); }
            }
        }
        csMonitorTryEnter.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Monitor.TryEnter (2): " + csMonitorTryEnter.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

        Stopwatch csMonitorEnter = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < lockIterations; ) {
            Monitor.Enter(object1);
            try { i++; } finally { Monitor.Exit(object1); }
        }
        csMonitorEnter.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Monitor.Enter: " + csMonitorEnter.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the full "thick" monitor was only set up on the first *contended* lock? Otherwise doesn't it just use a flag in the syncblock?

Comment: Marc, have go got any references to prove that 'in 4.0 lock is not Monitor.Enter'. That seems highly unlikely to me.

Comment: @Steven: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: @Steven: see also the post by Michał Bendowski on this question.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember Eric Lippert's article. From your answer I was assuming that C# 4.0 didn't use `Monitor.Enter` anymore, but that’s not what you actually said. You’re right that that particular overload of `Monitor.Enter` isn’t used anymore.

Comment: Updated link for anyone seeing this more recently: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix

Answer (score 3):

may it be because lock is Monitor.Enter, not Monitor.TryEnter?

Comment: Same results with Monitor.Enter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .NET reflector to inspect the generated IL. The `lock` keyword uses `Monitor.Enter` instead of `Monitor.TryEnter` - here's the short answer to your question. Here's how your code looks like when disassembled and translated back to C#:

```
public void Lock_Performance_Test()
{
    Stopwatch csLock = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        object CS$2$0000;
        bool <>s__LockTaken0 = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(CS$2$0000 = this.object1, ref <>s__LockTaken0);
            i++;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (<>s__LockTaken0)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(CS$2$0000);
            }
        }
    }
    csLock.Stop();
    Stopwatch csMonitor = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(this.object1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)))
        {
            try
            {
                i++;
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(this.object1);
            }
        }
    }
    csMonitor.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Lock: {0:f1} microseconds", csLock.Elapsed.Ticks / 10M);
    Console.WriteLine("Monitor.TryEnter: {0:f1} microseconds", csMonitor.Elapsed.Ticks / 10M);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is presumably the C# 4.0 compiler - with earlier compilers the IL will be slightly different (around the overload that is called, and the `bool` local).

Answer (score -1):

If you need speed doing this, then SpinLock is a far better choice in my experience.

```
public class DisposableSpinLock : IDisposable {
    private SpinLock mylock;
    private bool isLocked;

    public DisposableSpinLock( SpinLock thelock ) {
        this.mylock = thelock;
        mylock.Enter( ref isLocked );
    }

    public DisposableSpinLock(  SpinLock thelock, bool tryLock) {
        this.mylock = thelock;
        if( tryLock ) {
            mylock.TryEnter( ref isLocked );
        } else {
            mylock.Enter( ref isLocked );
        }
    }

    public bool IsLocked { get { return isLocked; } }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose( true );
        GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing ) {
        if( disposing ) {
            if( isLocked ) {
                mylock.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is a nice useful way to get things to work "automatically" in abort and exception cases.

You can just create a SpinLock instead of the "lock" object, and then use:

```
using( new DisposableSpinLock( myLock ) ) {
     // Under lock and key...
}
```

This allows you to get the same single line of code that lock() provides while also dealing with the required try {} finally{} behavior and have a bit more control over what happens to cleanup the object.

I also have support for the "try" case which would be written using code blocks with an extra if statement inside:

```
using( theLock = new DisposableSpinLock( myLock, true ) ) {
    if( theLock.IsLocked ) {
        // Under Lock and Key
    }
}
```

SpinLock is not not CPU friendly for highly contended locks because of the added CPU use of SpinLock in that situation, but for the locks that are pretty much synchronized and just need occasionally locking for outside references or occasional second thread access, this is a big win.

Yes, this is not gorgeous, but for me, SpinLocks have made everything that I have for lightly contended locks much more performant.

http://www.adammil.net/blog/v111_Creating_High-Performance_Locks_and_Lock-free_Code_for_NET_.html is a good look at spin locks and locking overall.

Comment: DO NOT pass SpinLock to method/constructor because it's a value type and you pass a copy. It will result in a total lack of synchronization. To make this code works as expected you need to use ref modifier.